# convert ticks to time_t or Filetime()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

How do I convert ticks to time_t or filetime()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time_t` is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) as the number of seconds from the Unix epoch date January 1, 1970 @ 00:00 UTC.  So, you basically need to figure out how much time your ticks represent and subtract the epoch time.  The following should do it.

```
double GetTimeTSecondsFrom(long ticks)
{
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return (new DateTime(ticks) - epoch).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: this is great... 
also plese can u tell me how to convert from time_t to ticks
thanks

Comment: To perform the inverse operation, just add `epoch.Ticks` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_t_value).TotalTicks`.

Answer (score 1):

For time_t:

```
long ticks =  633918528000000000;
DateTime target = new DateTime(ticks);
DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
double time_t = (target - start).TotalSeconds;
```