# convert time_t to ticks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that convert ticks to time_t format

```
 long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

       long tt = GetTimeTSecondsFrom(ticks);

  long GetTimeTSecondsFrom(long ticks)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return (long) (new DateTime(ticks) - epoch).TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Now i am confused how to convert it back to ticks with some mathematical formula and not with a function.

Any suggestions...??

thanks

Let me take a general case and explain.
DateTime.Now.Ticks give me a value 633921719670980000 which is in tics

then i convert this in time_t with the above function and get tt = 1256575167

now i want to convert this back to 633921719670980000. for this i need a formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date`1970-01-01 00:00:00 Z`is exactly 62,135,596,800 seconds (621,355,968,000,000,000 ticks), so to convert a`DateTime`tick count into a`time_t`value you could just scale it (divide by 10,000,000) to get seconds, and then subtract that offset.

To go the other way, do the reverse: add the offset seconds to the`time_t`value, then scale it (multiply by 10,000,000) to get ticks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was given as a comment to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613853/convert-ticks-to-timet-or-filetime) regarding converting ticks to time_t.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_t_value).Ticks + epoch.Ticks;
```

Comment: it gives an error 'System.TimeSpan does not contain a definition for 'TotalTicks'and no extension method'TotalTicks........

Comment: I just copied and pasted from the original comment.  It is .Ticks, not .TotalTicks, which is easily discoverable using the Intellisense.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: so there is no formula to do this.... i ask this because i need to use it in my databasequery.... i have store in time_t then convert it to ticks and diplay a date in a particular format which i get by manipulating the ticks...

Comment: You shouldn't need a formula in your database.  Just ensure that you always convert from ticks to time_t before sending it to the database and convert form time_t to ticks after loading it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) documentation:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

So, a function to convert seconds to ticks would look something like:

```
long GetTicksFromSeconds(long seconds)
{
    return seconds * 10000000;
}
```

Comment: this will not give me the value i want... please have a look at my edited part to get the clear picture.. thanks