# UTC time in ticks (since 01/01/0001 00:00:00)

Tags: php, time, epoch

I'm trying to integrate with a third party service that wants to know how many "UTC time in ticks (since 01/01/0001 00:00:00)" have passed.

What is a tick?

Assuming it's a second (and I don't know that it is)...  how am I supposed to do it since 01/01/0001 00:00:00? That's bigger than a 32-bit integer. Not sure if it's bigger than a 64-bit integer but PHP's date() functions return 32-bit integers - not 64-bit ones.

If I knew how many seconds had elapsed between 01/01/0001 00:00:00 and UNIX epoch I could use bcmath or gmp to add that amount (as a constant) to time() (again assuming ticks are seconds) but I don't know what that number would be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the service written in .NET as the .NET framework knows DateTime.Ticks. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) says about a tick:

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

So you'll have to multiple seconds since 01/01/0001 00:00:00 by 10.000.000.

I found the value:

```
621,355,968,000,000,000
```

for the ticks from 01-01-0001T00:00:00 until 01-01-1970 in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627067/convert-time-t-to-ticks). I don't know how it has been calculated. I assume the .NET framework will output it. I would suggest to verify the value and declare it as a constant in PHP as you mentioned.

PHP's int type is a signed integer. Its size depends on the system you are using. If its a 64bit system the value range should be large enough for the purpose. If not you can use the [GMP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.examples.php) or the [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension for working woth large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard definition for "ticks". Could mean seconds, 50ths, 60ths, or 100ths of a second, milliseconds, or any number of other subdivisions. You'll need to ask the service provider for details.

If they want you to count from year 1, that raises all sorts of other troublesome questions, because the Gregorian calendar (the one we use nowadays) wasn't introduced until 1582! (Nor was the concept of UTC standardized until 1961.) The service provider may or may not be taking the calendar change into account.

One easy way to check all of this will be to ask them what the value corresponding to now (or to some other recent reference date) is.

Answer (score -2):

Unix time is the seconds passed since Jan 1, 1970. Of course you can use special library such as bcmath to add the timestamp. The unix time is 1970 years later than the UTC time so the constant will be 1970*365*24*60*60 seconds.

Comment: That's not what the question asked

Comment: @therefromhere It IS what the question ask. (By the way, the constant doesn't count leap years.)

Comment: I think the main part of the question is what is a tick.